# Ubuntu 22.04.4 laptop touchpad is working but the keyboard is not working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

First of all, my keyboard works on the bios screen and the grub screen. I installed Ubuntu, first time and the installation was successful, but I noticed that my keyboard did not work in the system, including the installation.
Then I tried some solutions, first I did `sudo evtest` and the result is as follows:

[image: evtest]

And I tried:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

And I tried another solution after that.

```
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
```

When I type it into the console, I get "10".

And I tried:

```
sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I added a line to the file:

```
# bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it
blacklist intel_vbtn
```

I saved it and rebooted, but it didn't work. I'm typing all this on a USB keyboard. My USB keyboard works.